# How to share data between two event handler?

Tags: ocaml, reason, bucklescript

I'm playing with reason and buckelscript, and as an exercise I created bindings for `http.get` (https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v8.x/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback)

Using this bindings I would like to code this simple snippet

```
http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1', (res) => {
  let results = [];
  res.on('data', (chunk) => { results.push(chunk) });
  res.on('end', () => {
    console.log(results.join())
  });
});
```

That I'm trying to use like this in reason

```
Http.Client.get("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1", response => {
  let results = [];
  Http.IncomingMessage.on(
    response,
    `data(
      data => {
        // Append data to results here, but how ? This line does not compile
        results = [data, ...results];
      },
    ),
  );

  Http.IncomingMessage.on(
    response,
    `_end(() => {
      // Print results
      Js.log("END")
    })
  )
});
```

`results` is immutable, a new binding will not be accessible from the `end` callback. Does you have an idea how to solve that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function `on` has type

```
(t, [ | `_end(unit => unit) | `data(Buffer.t => unit)]) => unit
```

thus if you want to establish a communication channel between two calls to `on` the only choice you have is to use some side-effectful computation, i.e., a [mutable reference](https://reasonml.github.io/docs/en/mutation.html), I/O channel, etc.

If you want to adhere to a more functional programming style then you should consider changing the return type of your handlers to some inhabited type, e.g., `(t, ...) => result`

Usually, such style will involve using [Promises](https://reasonml.github.io/docs/en/promise.html), i.e., when a return value of a handler is a promise. This enables a style of programming where asynchronous event handlers may safely communicate with each other without explicit mutability.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this precious feedback, I will investigate both of the solutions. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it using this code

```
Http.Client.get("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1", response => {
  let results = [||];
  response
  |. Http.IncomingMessage.on(
       `data(
         data => {
           let results = Array.append(results, [|data|]);
           response
           |. Http.IncomingMessage.on(
                `_end(
                  () =>
                    Js.log(
                      results |> Buffer.concatArray |> Buffer.toString,
                    ),
                ),
              );
         },
       ),
     );
});
```

It works, but I'm quite sure this is not the most efficient way to do it.

Comment: you can use `let results = ref []` to create a reference to a result of type list. So that you can later update it as `results := new_element :: !results` (if it is the correct reason syntax). Though it doesn't sound very functional... 
Can you provide a reference to the `Http` module that you're using?

Comment: Here is the full code I'm using, but everything is in progress https://github.com/thomasthiebaud/reason-lambda